# Since we use Bootsrap to approximate the SE, can we use Bootstrap to find prediction errors?

Tags: cross-validation, bootstrap, computational-statistics

Instead of using Cross-validation, or K-fold Cross-validation, can we use Bootstrap to generate random samples and use one of them as test set, and others as training set?

Comment: Two bootstrap samples will include many observations in common, which leaves you with the problem of mostly testing on your training data

Comment: Do you mean that since we use our initial data set to obtain bootstrap sample, we have overlaps in data. Hence, our model would essentially use the fraction of data that we used for training, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Glen_b said, training on one bootstrap set and testing the other will have substantial overlap ($\approx 40\,\%$ of the cases will be in both sets), thus the error will have an optimistic bias.

But you can train on bootstrap sets and then test the left out cases ($\approx \frac{n}{e} \approx 37\,\%$ of the cases), this is called out-of-bootstrap error.

Comment: How did you calculate the overlap percentage?

Comment: @ZamirAkimbekov: probability that a particular case is drawn into one bootstrap sample has limit ($n \to \infty$) $1 - \frac{1}{e}$. Both draws are independent, so probability to draw any particular case into both sets is $\approx (1 - \frac{1}{e})^2 \approx 0.4$.